# Big SQL table. Is there a better way than ntext?

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to fix a legacy system. It's a VB6 app on a SQL DB. They have a database table that's over a gig. It doesn't actually have a lot of rows. The reason is a lot of text in RTF format that is stored in an ntext field. Is there any way to reduce the size of the table without major surgery to the app?

Thanks a lot
Mark

Answer (score 1):

What's broken? If it works, I'd say leave it. Otherwise describe the problem. A gig isn't by any means a prohibitive table size, esp. if there are few rows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked with Management studio/Enterprise manager to the free space of that database? Maybe it has a lot of free space inside from older deleted data, or maybe the log has grown up too big and can be truncated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestions. This site is cool! The table in question has 4000 rows. I've figured out that there's 100 big rows with 1 gig of data. The fools who designed this thing allow users to  "paste" files in there - pdfs and docs etc. Not much I can do apart from ask the users to tidy up those 100 records.